Can we see Accessibility Identifiers alone of automation elements in swift which are not accessibility Elements
I want to expose few elements for accessibility alone and other for automation alone. But I can only accessibility elements in Accessibility Inspector but can't see Automation Elements
self.view.accessibilityElements = [loginButton as Any,
                                   registerButton as Any,
                                   closeButton as Any]
self.view.automationElements = [claimLabel as Any,
                               loginButton as Any,
                               registerButton as Any,
                               intoductionImage as Any,
                               closeButton as Any])

